# How to get range value of a ex-mode command in Lua?

Tags: neovim, lua

I want to get the range of ex-mode command in Lua(eg `1` and `3` in `1;3d`). The range value should be stored as `a:firstline` and `a:lastline` in vim, but based on the [doc](https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua.html), `a` is not implemented in the `vim` table. How can I get them in Lua?

**Update**

This is the command I am trying to define:

```lua
        vim.api.nvim_exec(
            "command! -range " .. opts.ex_mode_cmd .. " <line1>,<line2>lua require('commented').toggle_comment('c')", true)
```

From this I expect I can get the value of `a:firstline` and `a:lastline` inside `toggle_comment`, but they all returned `nil`

```lua
local function toggle_comment()
  print('check range', vim.firstline, vim.lastline)
end
```

Comment: Can you please explain, from what you'd like to get the range? `a:firstline` and `a:lastline` are only ever valid from functions, that are define with the `range` attribute, but is not always readily available. So this only exists for custom vimscript functions. But I suppose that is not what you want here, it cannot be used to get arbitrarily ranges from ex commands like `:g` or `:m`

Comment: Are you defining a user-command? If so, see `:help :command-range` and then you can use `<line1>` and `<line2>` in the command definition to pass the range to whatever Lua code you call from there...

Comment: @filbranden Yes I am trying to define a user-command, and I guess it would work by passing `<line1>` and `<line2>` to the function. But since my function is not accepting start and end range as parameter originally, I want to avoid this unless I cannot find any other solution.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Sorry for missing that part. I have added the code I am writing back in.

Comment: It looks like the code you mentioned will work in Vim, at least the documentation mentions `vim.firstline` and `vim.lastline`. In NeoVim, the `:lua` command takes a range, but no idea where it actually stashes it...

Comment: Yes exactly. So that's why I am opening this question here. But I guess I will use `<line1>`, and `<line2>` for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

This is works for me:

```
command -range Test lua require('test').test_range(<line1>, <line2>)
```

```lua
function test_range(start, end)
  print(start, end)
end
```